# Installing Ubuntu Server 20.04 on APU Board (Headless) - Fails at "executing late commands"

Tags: boot, command-line, server, cloud

APU Board is a router board with headless installation via Console. The state I have now is that it runs up via console I use a "cloud-init" auto install script.

This works perfectly on my virtual machine (with GUI). But with APU Board it did not boot. So I added to the txt.cfg the following:

```
serial 0 115200
console 0

default live
label live
  menu label ^Install
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append   initrd=/casper/initrd quiet --- autoinstall ip=dhcp ds=nocloud-net;s=https://mydomain/autoinstall/
```

Now when it boots on APU board it enters a state where it says "boot" and I can enter the following to start the cloud-init script to load:

```
Could not initialize gfx
boot: live console=ttyS0,115200n8
```

Everything runs smoothly just as the GUI version on virtual machine. But when it comes to "executing late commands" it just stops. No buttons to press or anything.

[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdXsn.png)

But on the virutal one it goes though and runs all the commands I've given in the cloud-init script:

```
- "cp -r /target/etc/skel /target/home/setup"
- "cp /cdrom/.setup /target/root/setup"
- "cp /cdrom/.setup.sh /target/root/setup.sh"
- "chmod +x /target/root/setup*"
- "curtin in-target --target=/target -- useradd -s /bin/bash -p *redacted* setup"
- "curtin in-target --target=/target -- chown -fR setup:setup /home/setup"
- "touch /target/etc/sudoers.d/setup"
- "echo setup ALL =NOPASSWD: /root/setup.sh > /target/etc/sudoers.d/setup"
- "echo sudo /root/setup.sh >> /target/home/setup/.bashrc"
- "echo logout >> /target/home/setup/.bashrc"
```

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Updated title to have 20.04 in it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in 20.04.2 version of the server ISO.

A newly released 20.04.3 works flawlessly. That is 1 week of work I'll never get back.